# tableau sort rownames as data source order

Tags: sorting, matrix, tableau-api, rdata

i have a rdata file that looks like this when i import into Tableau:

```
Rownames(Abc) cat(#) mouse(#) dog(#)
cat            1.0    0.8     0.7
mouse          0.8    1.0     0.5
dog            0.7    0.5     1.0
```

When i put `measure names` into `Columns` box and sort it to `data source order`, i can get it to become in the cat, dog, mouse order as in my data source.

However when i put `rownames` into the `Rows` box and sort it on `data source order`, it doesnt work. It seems to be able to sort only on ascending or descending.

I have `measure values` in the `color` box so i have some sort of correlation matrix. I need the matrix to be in the `data source order` of `cat mouse dog` for both row and column in order to see something useful.

Right now i am only seeing this:

```
rownames cat mouse dog
mouse 
dog
cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't 100% clear for me what you meant, but it sounded like your problem is that the order in the rows is by alphabet and not custom how it is defined in your source file?

In that case you can right click on the measure pill in the row drawer, click on "Sort", choose "Manual" and reorder however you like.
In case you want to apply it to bigger data sets, as far as I am aware you cannot just keep the order from your source. A workaround would be to calculate an ID field beforehand so that you can sort ascending on it once you display it in Tableau.

Edit:
The difference between columns and rows is the following:
Columns are defined in your data source. If you have a DB you will define the order and type of the columns, in a CSV you have the first line that gives the order and name of the columns. that's important if you want to read or write because you need to be sure that eg the 2nd column contains the value for cats.

Rows on the other side are added more or less randomly (at least usually). You get a new dataset and it's appended at the end. That means there is no order unless you have a layer above the data entry that actually takes care of that.
When you read these rows now it usually makes more sense to sort them ascending or descending by value or name rather than taking the random order form the source.

As stated above if you want to work around this, you will have to assign an ID to every row, so that you can sort it.

Comment: buy why is it that when i put the measure names variable in the col drawer, it keeps it as source data format. When i put the rownames variable in the row drawer and it doesnt work. Why does it work for col but not rows?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Comment: what to you mean by assigning the ID to each row? I have ID and it doesnt work. do you mean id as prefix of each row value?